Facing the issue where FormData is not being retrieved in MSW, possibly due to an async/await problem?
I am writing one test case to test my component which on upload calls this api, this api could return 2 responses i.e failure or success. I want to test both conditions based on filename coming in request formdata.
I am only able to test one case because if I am trying to get formData by using async await in msw, it is not working, it stops execution there and does not return anything.
http.post(
`https://mydomain/upload`,
async ({ request }) => {
const info = await request.formData();
console.log('info--------------', info);
return HttpResponse.json(bulkUploadErrorResponse.FAILED);
}
)

My test case looks like this
test('success message should appear on screen when a correct bulk file is uploaded', async () => {
renderWithAllProvider(<MyComponent />);

const file = generateXLSXFile('Sample Content', 'testFile');
const fileInput = screen.getByTestId('file-upload');

// eslint-disable-next-line
await act(async () => {
console.log('Uploading file ......');
await userEvent.upload(fileInput, file);
});

// eslint-disable-next-line
expect(
await screen.findByText(
'Bulk Upload for the inventory has been successfully uploaded!'
)
);
});

